# Jena reasoning: dynamically adding new resources in the conclusion

Tags: jena, reasoning, jena-rules

From what I have seen so far, all Jena reasoning rules are in the form below :

```
[hirarchyExpansion:
(?x dbo:isPartOf ?loc)
(?loc dbo:isPartOf ?highloc)
->
(?x dbo:isPartOf ?highloc)
]
```

This implies that no new resource can be added in the conclusion. What I need is to dynamically name and add new resources in the conlcusion of a rule.
Can somebody please refer me to the solution?

Comment: You can create new resources using the Jena rules.  Can you give a concrete example of what you'd like to be able to do though, so that we have something concrete to respond to?

Comment: Also, have a look at the [builtins](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#RULEbuiltins) that you can use in Jena rules.  In particular, you might be interested in uriConcat, makeTemp, makeInstance, and makeSkolem.

Comment: What Joshua suggests seems like the solution you are looking for. I just want to note, perhaps you know it, that this way you may run into termination issues.